# Como puedo exportar cierto rango de excel a pdf?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, macros

Tengo este codigo, pero solo me exporta a pdf las hojas, y asi como esta me lanza error

```
Sheets(Array("Food Pres!E3:M19", "currentMonth!E3:M19", "ChartModel!E3:M19", "Rating6M!E3:M19")).Select

'Save sheets to pdf file

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    myfolder & myfile _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Qué error te muestra?

Comment: Run-time error '9'
Subscript out of range

Comment: Pero es que en tú código sólo le dices que exporte a PDF la hoja activa. Aunque previamente hayas seleccionado más hojas (y rangos de estas hojas) no se puede hacer así.

Para exportar un rango tienes que hacer algo así:
'''
Sheets("Food Pres").Range("E3:M19").ExportAsFixedFormat ... 
''' y a continuación el resto de código.

Del modo que lo estás intentando no lo vas a conseguir.

Comment: Public Function TOPDF()
'Save sheets to pdf file

Sheets("Food Press").Range("E3:M19").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    myfolder & myfile _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Function

De esta manera dices? lo intento y no funciona

Comment: Qué error muestra?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147352565(8002000b)':
The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.